# Rearrangement step by step

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would like to know how to get from here:

$$\large{k^2(x^2 - 2vxt + v^2t^2) + y^2 + z^2 = c^2a^2(t^2 - 2bxt + b^2x^2)}$$

to here:

$$\large{(k^2 - b^2a^2c^2)x^2 - 2(k^2v - ba^2c^2)xt + y^2 + z^2 = \bigg(a^2 - \frac{k^2v^2}{c^2}\bigg)c^2t^2}$$

Comment: Do you considering over taking term from one side to other side?

Comment: yeah, it's probably really simple, but I fail to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{align*} k^2x^2-2vxtk^2+v^2t^2k^2+y^2+z^2 &=c^2a^2t^2-2bxtc^2a^2+b^2x^2c^2a^2 \\
\Leftrightarrow k^2x^2-b^2x^2c^2a^2 -2vxtk^2+2bxtc^2a^2 +y^2+z^2 &= c^2a^2t^2-v^2t^2k^2\\
\Leftrightarrow (k^2-b^2c^2a^2)x^2 -2(vk^2-bc^2a^2)xt+y^2+z^2 &= (c^2a^2 - \frac{c^2}{c^2} v^2k^2)t^2=(a^2-\frac{v^2k^2}{c^2})c^2t^2
\end{align*}
$